# How to use the value of lookup field in soql so that I can display all the records related to that user?

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to get all the records related to the user I select from the lookup field in the visual-force page after clicking the search button.
But the problem is I am not able to compare the value of lookup field in the apex class in soql query.
The code is working for the text value as if I use the  then i can pass the text value and for this text value the code works but when I try the same thing for lookup field it gives me error.

[image: Error message when I try to compare the lookup field value]

in the below code 'Daily_Record__c' is the custom object having the lookup relation with the 'User' standard object.

Apex code :-

```
  <apex:inputfield value="{!Daily_Record__c.Username__c}"/>

   <apex:inputtext value="{!strAccSearchString}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!SearchAccountRec}"/>       
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="true" title="Search Result">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstAccount}" var="acc">
             <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!acc.id}">{!acc.Username__c}</apex:outputLink>        
            </apex:column>  
            <apex:column >
            </apex:column>                    
        </apex:pageBlockTable>          
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!If(lstAccount.size==0 && isResultDisplay == true,true,false)}" title="Search Result">           
        <apex:pageblockSection >
            <apex:outputLabel value="No Result Found"></apex:outputLabel>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
```

extensions :

```
public class workshop {
    public workshop(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    } 
    public String strAccSearchString {get; set;}
    public List<Daily_Record__c> lstAccount {get; set;}
    public List<Daily_Record__c> lstAccount1 {get; set;}
    public boolean isResultDisplay {get; set;}
    public workshop(){
      lstAccount = new List<Daily_Record__c>();
        isResultDisplay = false;
    }
     public void SearchAccountRec(){
        isResultDisplay = true;
       string strLikeString = '%'+strAccSearchString+'%';
        string strSOQL = 'select Username__c from Daily_Record__c  where Username__c like :strLikeString';
        lstAccount = database.query(strSOQL);
   } 

}
```

please help me to solve this....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use dot notation in SOQL to get some field value of a lookup reference object.

I assume `Username__c` field on `Daily_Record__c` object is a lookup on `User` object. You want to make a SOQL and filter `User.Name`  field.

```
String strSOQL = 'select Username__c from Daily_Record__c  where Username__r.Name like :strLikeString';
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it shows me error as show below
System.QueryException: Didn't understand relationship 'Username__c' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
Error is in expression '{!SearchAccountRec}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page view_record: Class.ctrlSearch.SearchAccountRec: line 19, column 1

Comment: @TanmayKakde I have just updated my answer. For relationship __r should be used. Username__r

Comment: Thank u sir now it is working thanks for your help

Comment: one more help I want sir Can I auto populate the value of lookup field in to text field so that I need not to copy and paste that value to my <apex:inputtext> field to  search the record related to the user for which I am searching

Comment: @TanmayKakde I think you can create this as another question